# Convert sql to linq with STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, linq

convert sql to linq  that has STRING_AGG

```
SELECT
    V.pkid,
    V.[Name] AS VendorName,
    SFTP.SFTP_Paths AS SFTP_Paths
FROM
    dbo.Vendor V
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            connected_to,
            STRING_AGG(rootfolder, ', ') AS SFTP_Paths
        FROM
            dbo.FTP
        WHERE
            connected_to_type = 4 -- Vendor
        GROUP BY
            connected_to
    ) SFTP ON v.pkid = SFTP.connected_to
WHERE
    V.active = 1
order by
    V.[name]
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output as well.

Comment: If you ask about EF Core, it is not possible without third-party extensions: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22957

Comment: You probably have a requirement that resulted in this SQL. It would be nice if you edited the question and gave us the requirement. So we won't have to interpret your SQL hoping we can extract the requirement. Furthermore: what are (the essential parts of) your classes?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x? What database engine?

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the same sql query result.
Instead of `STRING_AGG (rootfolder, ',') AS SFTP_Paths` I used `SFTP_Paths = string.Join(",", b.Select (c => c.rootfolder).ToArray())` for equivalence.
The rest of the query is understandable.

```
var query = vendorList.Join(lstFtp.Where(x => x.connected_to_type == 4).GroupBy(a => a.connected_to)
    .Select(b => new
    {
         connected_to = b.Key,
         SFTP_Paths = b.Select(c => c.rootfolder).ToList()
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(b => new
    {
        connected_to = b.connected_to,
        SFTP_Paths = string.Join(",", b.SFTP_Paths).ToArray()
    }),
    right => right.pkid,
    left => left.connected_to,
    (right, left) => new
    {
        V = right,
        SFTP = left
    }).Where(d => d.V.active == 1)
    .Select(e => new
    {
        pkid = e.V.pkid,
        VendorName = e.V.Name,
        SFTP_Paths = e.SFTP.SFTP_Paths
    })
    .OrderBy(e => e.VendorName).ToList();
```

Comment: What LINQ to database did you test with?

Comment: If you didn't test with an actual database, I doubt if this works. No version of EF can translate `String.Join` to SQL that I know of.

Comment: @NetMage Yes EF does not allow the use of extensions. I modified the code. It works right now.

Comment: I would suggest `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` (on the main query).